# Use docker in self-hosted bitbucket runner

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I would like to run docker commands in my bitbucket pipeline. And the runner I am using is self-hosted linux shell that runs on an ec2 instance. However, I am getting `Configuration error: The Docker feature is not supported on this self-hosted runner's platform.` when the pipeline is triggered. I do have docker installed on the ec2.
Is there any other configurations that I am missing?

My pipeline script:

```
  - step:
    name: 'runner'
    runs-on:
      - self.hosted
      - linux.shell
      - asg
    script:
      - echo "test"
      - docker run busybox
    services:
      - docker
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there could be problem with order.
Services should be before script.

If this does not resolve the problem try to define docker dind image.

> image: docker:20.10.7-dind